# Ошибка при push на репозитории на Github

Tags: git, github

При попытке запушить коммиты в гитхаб репозитории, получил сообщение:

> batch response: This repository is over its data quota. Account responsible for LFS bandwidth should purchase more data packs to restore access.
>   error: failed to push some refs to '[repoURL]'

Я использую Git-LFS. По всей видимости, у меня файлы весят больше 1,5гб, как обычно гитхаб дает. Вопрос: это ограничение только на месяц, или нужно отключить LFS?

Answer (score 0):

Это проблема больших файлов. Вот ссылки для изучения:

https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/working-with-large-files
https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/what-is-my-disk-quota